# Does ntp_gettime() actually return nanosecond precision?

Tags: linux, ubuntu-12.04, ntp

The following code on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <sys/timex.h>
 #include <sys/time.h>

 int main(int argc, char **argv) 
 {
     struct timeval tv; 
     gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);

     struct ntptimeval ntptv;
     ntp_gettime(&ntptv);

     printf("gettimeofday: tv_sec = %ld, tv_usec = %ld\n", 
                tv.tv_sec, tv.tv_usec);
     printf("ntp_gettime:  tv_sec = %ld, tv_usec = %ld\n", 
                ntptv.time.tv_sec, ntptv.time.tv_usec);
 }
```

returns:

```
 gettimeofday: tv_sec = 1366209548, tv_usec = 137736
 ntp_gettime:  tv_sec = 1366209548, tv_usec = 137743081
```

This is kind of weird because the `tv_usec` value, if it indeed is the microsecond count, should not be greater than 1000000.  The result shown above makes me think that `ntp_gettime()` is actually returning nanosecond precision.

The `ntp_gettime()` manpage (for precise) at http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man2/ntp_gettime.2freebsd.html 
doesn't really say much.

An earlier manpage version (for hardy) 
http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man2/ntp_gettime.2.html claims it might be either nanosecond or microsecond depending on whether the `STA_NANO` bit is set in the `status` word returned by `ntp_adjtime()`.

Anyone know definitively?  Short of that, where are `ntp_gettime()`, `ntp_adjtime()`, and all the various internal functions they call defined in the 12.04 source?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ntp_gettime` and `ntp_adjtime` are both defined in the C library. On Linux and glibc, `ntp_adjtime` is just a wrapper for the `adjtimex` system call, and `ntp_gettime` uses the same syscall by passing it a `struct timex` with `modes` set to 0. You can browse their definitions at [the glibc LXR](http://koala.cs.pub.ro/lxr/#glibc+2.9/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/ntp_gettime.c).

The system call [implementation](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/time.c#L209) calls [_do_adjtimex](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/time/timekeeping.c#L1666) which calls [getnstimeofday](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/time/timekeeping.c#L331) to get the time (in nanoseconds) and then hands it to [__do_adjtimex](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/time/ntp.c#L641). And here is the interesting part :

```c
txc->time.tv_sec = ts->tv_sec;
txc->time.tv_usec = ts->tv_nsec;
if (!(time_status & STA_NANO))
        txc->time.tv_usec /= NSEC_PER_USEC;
```

So if `STA_NANO` is set it just puts the nanosecond value in `tv_usec`, which is the behavior you've been experiencing. If you want to unset this flag, you can do something like this :

```c
struct timex tmx;
tmx.modes = 0 | ADJ_MICRO;
ntp_adjtime(&tmx);
```

and then read your microsecond value from `tmx.time.tv_usec`. If you want to do this you'll have to run your code with `sudo`, but beware that the flag will remain unset in the kernel until you reset it (using `ADJ_NANO`) or reboot.